# 6" faucet hoses seem to be unavailable, what do I do with an old design?

Tags: faucet, hose

I'm replacing a faucet on a pedestal sink.  The supply hoses are the old plastic rather than the modern braided ones and I would much prefer to upgrade the old (21 years) hoses.  Unfortunately, I'm having zero luck finding hoses that short.  As it's a pedestal sink I don't see how to use a longer one without it sticking out and being ugly.

Any solutions?

Comment: A picture would help, but I have found that using overly long hoses that then loop back up to the fixtures allows you to tuck/hide the excess behind (or in) the pedestal.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it I was thinking that might be the only answer but keeping them out of sight is problematic.  The pedestal is only 6" wide, inside is mostly the drain pipe.  Maybe if I got long ones and zip-tied them to keep them narrow enough...

Comment: Yup, get real long ones and let them droop down next to the drain pipe, then tape or zip-tie them in place!

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Worked.  Make it an answer if you want it accepted.  I didn't even need the zip-ties, I was able to tuck them against the valves, they're out of sight.

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use overly long hoses that then loop back up to the fixtures, this should allow you to tuck/hide the excess behind (or in) the pedestal.

Answer (score 3):

[Ace Hardware](http://www.acehardware.com/product/index.jsp?productId=52751656) has 6" supply lines on tap. The bad pun is free.

Comment: Unfortunately, I followed Jimmy Fix-it's solution before finding that.  For some reason it didn't come up in a Google search.

Comment: @LorenPechtel you should mark the check mark ✅ next to Jimmy Fit-it answer if that’s was your solution. 

Comment: @Tyson I hadn't accepted his answer yet because I hadn't been on since he posted it.